# Error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'int [2]' to 'int (&&)[2]'

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, std, stdvector

I haven't programmed in a while, so my code might be a bit sloppy. The only thing the program does is create a 4x4 bool grid with only the top left value true. It then runs it with the checkAdjacentTiles, that should return the tiles touching it (the one to the right and the one underneath). I get an error instead. I have a feeling this has to do with my vector: `std::vector<int[2]> checkAdjacentTiles(bool[4][4]);`, since the int [2]. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int[2]> checkAdjacentTiles(bool[4][4]);

int main() {
    bool grid[4][4];

    grid[0][0] = 1;
    std::vector<int[2]> temp = checkAdjacentTiles(grid);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)temp.size(); i++) {
        printf("(%i, %i)\n", temp[i][0], temp[i][1]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

std::vector<int[2]> checkAdjacentTiles(bool checkGrid[4][4]) {
    int relAdjacentSides[4][2] = { { -1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, -1 } };
    std::vector<int[2]> adjacentSides;

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                if (x + relAdjacentSides[i][0] >= 0 && x + relAdjacentSides[i][0] < 4) {
                    if (y + relAdjacentSides[i][1] >= 0 && y + relAdjacentSides[i][1] < 4) {
                        if (!checkGrid[x + relAdjacentSides[i][0], y + relAdjacentSides[i][1]]) {

                            bool stop = 0;
                            for (int v = 0; v < (int)adjacentSides.size(); v++) {
                                if (adjacentSides[v][0] == x + relAdjacentSides[i][0] && adjacentSides[v][1] == y + relAdjacentSides[i][1]) {
                                    stop = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!stop) {
                                adjacentSides.push_back({ x + relAdjacentSides[i][0], y + relAdjacentSides[i][1] });
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return adjacentSides;
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you [edit] your question to contain the full text of the error message.

Comment: You can't really make a vector<int[2]> because template deduction rules mean it decays to a vector<int*> (note the change means it's expecting you to manage the allocation/deallocation of the data). So perhaps your best bet is to declare a struct which contains the int[2] and then make a vector of those.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The full error message is in the title. There isn't anything more to that.

Comment: @qeadz I'm trying that right now, thanks!

Comment: You could also use a std::pair<int>.

Comment: @qeadz No, template type arguments aren't subject to decay.

Comment: But according to my reading of the standard, array types are banned as value types of containers because they aren't `Destructible` (C++11) or `Erasable` (C++14).

Comment: `std::array<int,2>` instead of `int[2]`

Comment: @Brian and the rest. I'm a bad programmer so what do you mean by decay and why exactly can't I use int[2] in a vector? Also does this work if adjacentSides is a std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>?  `adjacentSides.push_back({ any number here, any number here });`

Comment: Brian is right. My earlier comment is incorrect. Ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't use `int[2]` in a vector for some reason. I ended up using `std::pair<int,int>` instead and it works fine. Thanks jhnnslschnr.

Comment: The reason is that the elements of a vector must be both copy constructible and assignable. Arrays are neither.

Comment: @zenith Sorry, but what exactly do those two terms mean or where can I find what they mean? Thanks!

Comment: Assignable means you can use the assignment operator to copy the contents from `array2` to `array1` like this `array1 = array2`. Copy constructible means almost the same but that the copied-to object is *constructed* using the contents of another object, like this: `int array1[2] = array2`

Comment: As Yakk mentioned, there's also the [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container which behaves much like a raw array but with additional functionality, e.g. it is copy constructible and assignable.

Comment: @zenith I've already finished my program, but I think I'll check out  `std::array` for next time. Thanks!